# Upload Multiple Large Files via FTP with Progress Bar using ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, webforms, ftp

I need to upload large files (>2GB) to a web server, and ASP.NET has a 2GB file upload limit. So what i would like to know is, if its possible to upload files using FTP as i do with HTTP. In other words, is it possible to do an asyncronous (multiple) file upload with progress bar using FTP?

I already have a async file upload with progress bar using a handler (ashx) to send multiple files to a web server. Can i reuse this method to upload file via FTP, or do i need a totally different approach?

As mentioned i need to upload large files to a server, so any other solution that can help me accomplish the task would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve my issue using [ResumableJS](https://github.com/23/resumable.js)